# python how to convert json contains multiple arrays to pandas dataframe

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

hey im having trouble converting json to dataframe using pandas here is my solution

```
import json
import pandas as pd 
f = open('write.json')
data = json.load(f)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data,orient = 'index').reset_index()
print(df)
```

and here is the json file

```
{"_id":"60b53d92ccb1483964da45f9","Avg_sm":[26.66953125,26.66953125,26.666666666666668,26.666666666666668,26.666666666666668,26.666666666666668,26.666666666666668,26.666666666666668,26.6647859922179,26.6647859922179,26.45263157894737,26.45263157894737],"Avg_st":[22.6517578125,22.6517578125,22.65204678362573,22.65204678362573,22.65204678362573,22.65204678362573,22.65204678362573,22.65204678362573,22.65272373540856,22.65272373540856,22.694567062818336,22.694567062818336],"SensorCoordinates":[10.33363276545083,36.8434191667489],"SensorIdentifier":["CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC","CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC","CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC","CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC","CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC","CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC","CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC","CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC","CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC","CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC","CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC","CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC","CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC","CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC","CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC","CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC","CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC","CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC","CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC","CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC","CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC","CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC","CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC","CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC"],"count":24,"date":["25-06-2021","25-06-2021","25-06-2021","25-06-2021","25-06-2021","25-06-2021","25-06-2021","25-06-2021","25-06-2021","25-06-2021","25-06-2021","25-06-2021","25-06-2021","25-06-2021","25-06-2021","25-06-2021","25-06-2021","25-06-2021","25-06-2021","25-06-2021","26-06-2021","26-06-2021","26-06-2021","26-06-2021"],"min_sm":[21.1,21.1,21.1,21.1,21.1,21.1,21.1,21.1,21.1,21.1,21.1,21.1],"sensorId":["60b54789a21c170aecb25285","60b54789a21c170aecb25285","60b54789a21c170aecb25285","60b54789a21c170aecb25285","60b54789a21c170aecb25285","60b54789a21c170aecb25285","60b54789a21c170aecb25285","60b54789a21c170aecb25285","60b54789a21c170aecb25285","60b54789a21c170aecb25285","60b54789a21c170aecb25285","60b54789a21c170aecb25285","60b54789a21c170aecb25285","60b54789a21c170aecb25285","60b54789a21c170aecb25285","60b54789a21c170aecb25285","60b54789a21c170aecb25285","60b54789a21c170aecb25285","60b54789a21c170aecb25285","60b54789a21c170aecb25285","60b54789a21c170aecb25285","60b54789a21c170aecb25285","60b54789a21c170aecb25285","60b54789a21c170aecb25285"],"status":[true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true]}
```

Comment: look into json_normalize() or library flatten_json depending on how much flattening you need to do

Comment: What do you want your output to look like? Many of the nested lists have many different lengths which is problematic for making a DataFrame.

Comment: i want columuns to have the keys (_id,Avg_sm,...),and the rows for the values

Comment: hi! Did your query solved? if so then try considering [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so that the answer can be improved (or removed)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

you can try:

```
df=pd.json_normalize(data).apply(pd.Series.explode,ignore_index=True)
```

**OR**

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data,orient = 'index').T.apply(pd.Series.explode,ignore_index=True)
```